# « Hear!, Hear! » : variantes pour la marque d'approbation lors du discours/toast ?

Tags: expressions, anglais, salutations, régionalismes

En anglais on a l'expression « [*Hear(!)(,)Hear(!)*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hear,_hear) » ([1680](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=hear&allowed_in_frame=0), [*AHDotEL*](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=hear%20hear&submit.x=0&submit.y=0), [*Collins*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/hear-hear-#hear-hear-_1), [*Cambridge*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/fr/dictionnaire/anglais/hear-hear), [*Century*](http://triggs.djvu.org/century-dictionary.com/djvu2jpgframes.php?volno=04&page=85&query=hear%20hear), [*Merriam Learners*](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/hear), [*Dictionary.com*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hear?s=t)) pour *marquer l'approbation* pendant un discours ou lorsqu'une personne porte un toast par exemple, différemment du contexte du tête-à-tête. [*Collins Online*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/hear) le rend par « *bien dit !* ».

---

Qui dit mieux, et a-t-on des variantes (régionales, par exemple) ?

Comment: It’s probably more suitable (in French, at least)  for the “tete-a-tete” context which you correctly mention is not the same (hence the comment), but in English, I’d probably be more inclined to say “Right on, brother/sister,” or maybe even “Bull’s eye” or “Bingo” (even in public) than “Hear!, Hear!“, from which you could get perhaps  to “[Dans le mille](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/dans%20le%20mille)” in French.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

accord sur l'argumentaire:

- Oui !
- Tout à fait !
- C'est ça !

accord et encouragement :

- Ouaaaaais !

Comment: Attention à la façon de parler !! Ça pourrait facilement confondu avec de l'ironie/moquerie ! Ouais c'est ça ! (Cause toujours...)

Answer (score 4):

Je pense que l'on dirait plutôt *bravo*.

Answer (score 3):

In French, for expressing short, not overly disruptive agreement with words and ideas uttered **during**  a public discourse (which is your first example), for what it’s worth, I’d probably go more with [Fabrice Neyret's good answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/16409/hear-hear-variantes-pour-la-marque-dapprobation-lors-du-discours-toast/16411#16411) (Oui!; Tout à fait!; C'est ça!; & Ouaaaaais!); but that’s not to say that [Ikl's good answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/16409/hear-hear-variantes-pour-la-marque-dapprobation-lors-du-discours-toast/16410#16410) (Bravo) wouldn’t be more appropriate for expressing over-all agreement with a just **concluded** speech, **including a toast** (which is how your second example could be interpreted).

What little I have to add beyond the two good answers already given (+1 to them both) is possibly more suitable, especially in French, for a “tête-à-tête” context than for a public one,  which you correctly mention are not the same, but in English, I (being the hip dude that I mistakenly fashion myself to be) would probably be more inclined to say “Right on! or “Amen!” (with “Brother/Sister!” perhaps added in the right setting), even in a public setting than “Hear!, Hear!” (which I, perhaps just as mistakenly, find to be something that’s a tad old-fashioned [Old World?] and/or something that might be followed by a couple of “pips” and even a [Honey Nut] “Cheerio”!).

All gratuitous self-aggrandizing and fuddy-duddy-bashing aside, from these two hip alternatives to “Hear!, Hear!” in English perhaps you could arrive at:

“[En plein] **[Dans le mille](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/dans%20le%20mille)**”

in French to capture “Right-on!”/“Amen!” (cf: “bang-on/spot-on” from WordReference[dot]com);

and in the right setting you could even throw in:

“[dans le mille,] **[Émile](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/dans_le_mille,_%C3%89mile)**”

to hold the spot of “Brother/Sister” until something better comes along.

(“(Familier) (Par plaisanterie) Renforcement plaisant de dans le mille.” from  French Wiktionary)

(Note, I don't believe the speaker/toastmaster would have to be named "Emile" to use the last, rhyming suggestion, just as I believe that you could correctly and justifiably tell Papa Poule to "Relax, Max!")

Comment: Could you add in short what the answers you mention say? To avoid the "link-only" issue (with external content that can 404, plus lacking the all-relevant-info-in-one-place - mostly appreciated while browsing on phone but not only for that reason).

Comment: @JeromeJ Sorry about that! Sure, I'll get right on that clarification.  The two answers mentioned, "this good answer" and "this other good answer" (reminds me, now that you question it, of "this is my Brother Darryl, and this is my other Brother Darryl" from 'The Bob Newhart Show," so yeah it needs something!) are in fact just the two other answers posted so far to this question (Fabrice's and Ikl's). I've heard that some users prefer not seeing direct reference to their names/answers in other answers and I was clumsily just trying to avoid that.

Comment: Didn't know about that (weird...), thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @JeromeJ My pleasure! Now it's done for posterity in my edited answer. And thank you for reminding me of the valid 404 concern, as well as for drawing my attention to the phone-browsing one.

Comment: Thanks! I can hear _dans le mille_ being used indeed! Maybe this is also useful to render touché back in French... although that's an altogether different question...